# Driver not loaded when trying to access database in pyQt

Tags: sqlite, pyqt, driver

i'm coding in PyQT, in Ubuntu (using anaconda/spyder environment) and i'm trying to access a database by QSqlDatabase but
 `

```
    db = QSqlDatabase()
    db.addDatabase('QSQLITE',"SQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("test.db")
    if(db.open()):
        print("Opened!")
        db.close()
    else:
        print(db.lastError().databaseText())
        print(list(map(str, db.drivers())))
```

`

give me

Driver not loaded

['QSQLITE']

I have the sqlite file in /usr/include and /usr/lib and looked for an answer but most of all came from driver which were not available ( and mine seems to be ok ), mysql driver, on windows and on Qt so I didn't succed to solve it by looking the net.

Thanks for your answers !

Edit:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe93f5000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007efe41c7b000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007efe4210a000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007efe417a5000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007efe41423000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007efe41059000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007efe40e3c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007efe40c38000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007efe40a1e000)
libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007efe405bc000)
libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007efe40228000)
libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x00007efe3ffc2000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007efe3fcb1000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007efe3faa9000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007efe3f7a0000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007efe3f58a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007efe41f50000)
libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007efe3dad3000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007efe3d863000)
```

Comment: search for the folder sqldrivers inside the folder where you have installed PyQt5, in it you must make the file libqsqlite.so, locating the terminal in its folder run: `ldd libqsqlite.so`

Comment: I have : libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 and only 3 not found : libicui18n.so.58, libicuuc.so.58 and libicudata.so.58

Comment: No, look in the folder where PyQt5 is installed

Comment: I don't have any sqldrivers folder inside my PyQt5 folder

Comment: should have it since what returns `drivers()` depends on the content of that question. To do a simple search, install mlocate, execute: `sudo apt-get install mlocate`, then run `sudo updatedb`, and finally `locate *sqldrivers*`

Comment: Ok i found it ( sorry for the mistake ) and i've got  libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 and nothing miss

Comment: Do you only get one item?

Comment: No i  get 18 items buzt i can't copy all of them in a comment (too long)

Comment: Then edit your question and add it there, so others can use that information to suggest possible solutions.

Comment: What version of PyQt5 do you have installed? What version of Qt5 do you have installed?

Comment: PyQt version: 5.9.2

Comment: What version of Qt5 do you have installed?

Comment: QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the environment wasn't the probleme but my code is. By looking to much I skipped the begin ( I passed too quickly to the driver part in QSqlDatabase documentation).

QSqlDatabase::QSqlDatabase()

Creates an empty, invalid QSqlDatabase object.

So I just had to replace

```
db = QSqlDatabase()
db.addDatabase('QSQLITE',"SQLITE")
```

by the line :

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSLITE')
```

and my previous code gives me :

Opened!